# Can't use fab and tile configuration in vuetify3

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have a button with the bottom configuration in vuetify2.

```
<v-btn 
  fab
  tile
  icon
>
</v-btn>
```

I need this configuration in vuetify3. But the fab and tile configuration doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tile use :rounded="0".